# How to change the main object when user levelup?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a one object what is destroying by player, when user destroy the whole object he complete the level. So I want to load the next object (maybe prefab?) without change the scene. If the next objects will have to load, the best way to do it is if, for example, they have a higher number for higher level, eg Cube1, Cube2 ...

But to limit the interference in the code, it's best to do it so that all references are via the tag that will have all of the objects or is there a better way? I used the following code to load the new object myself, but I am talking about counting points, movement of the object, etc.

```
    GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Cubes2", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

If each of the following objects will have the same tag, how to simplify their loading in turn? If a player is promoted to level 3, Cube3 will have to load, how can I change this code to load in succession without adding 100 consecutive lines of code for each of the 100 objects?

Answer (score 1):

Conidering your level3 will have the build Index as 3 then you can try with buildIndex. otherwise you can use a variable to store current level number and concatinate it with "Cubes" string.

```
int LevelNum;
GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Cubes"+ LevelNum, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

You can change levelNum as soon as you upgrade players level.

Let me know if it helps.

EDIT: Removed the semicolon.

Comment: This will be only one scene where the meaning of level 3 its only change the object to 3 from prefabs. Without the change the scenes.

Comment: Then a variable to indicate level number and using it inside Resources.load will work.